# How to print the address of a float in c

Tags: c

I want to create a program that prints the address of an int, a float and a double.

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    float b;
    double c;
    printf("\na:%d \nb:%f \nc:%lf", &a, &b, &c);
}
```

But in the end all I get is the address of the int. For the other two the answer is 0.00000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use specifier `%p` to print address.

```
printf("\na:%p \nb:%p \nc:%p",(void *)&a,(void *)&b,(void *)&c);
```

Comment: You might want to add the necessary `void*`-casts.

Comment: @EOF Done that !! :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct format specifier for printing a memory address (pointer) is `%p`. You might as well cast the arguments into `(void*)` as the standard says that `%p` requires its arguments to be of type `void*`.

Using the wrong format specifier leads to *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

use `%p` to print address of `void`. `printf` doesn't seem to be able to pointer to `float` directly.

Try this: `printf("\na:%p \nb:%p \nc:%p", (void*)&a, (void*)&b, (void*)&c);`